# android, return command doesn't really return

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I got a weird behavior while debugging the below function (the context is Android, but this can be a general java question). Even when the if condition is true and the cursor jumps into "return true", it moves on and jump to "return false". And the behavior is reproducible! How can this be possible?

```
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
    if(super.onTap(p, mapView)) {//We tapped on an overlay item

        return true;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "jumping to return false");
    return  false;

}
```

Comment: I have similar things but I think it would require an actual Android / Dalvik dev to answer this question.

Comment: are you sure, this method gets called when you run your code in device/emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this many times in Eclipse debugger.  The method returns true, but the debugger makes a user think that it returns false :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have edit this java file when you debug the file. For example, delete a row or add a row and then the debug row is not the really is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Really, it's just a function of the way eclipsedebugger behaves. Rest assured 'return false' will not get executed in your example. I've seen this numerous times so I know exactly the issue you're seeing but like I said, it's just the way the debugger behaves but if the condition falls through, only true would actually be returned.